# Can't unpack linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-63-generic

Tags: kernel, dpkg

My kernel was recently updated from 5.8.0.59 to .63, but that broke my wireless adapter. It turns out I need the modules-extra which worked fine in .59, but nothing I have tried will get dpkg to unpack the .63 version.

It fails with an error similar to this one:
unable to open '/lib/modules/5.8.0-63-generic/kernel/drivers/net/dsa/vitesse-vsc73xx-spi.ko.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted

Except it fails on a different file every time I run it. I have re-downloaded the package several times from the ppa on the theory that the file was just corrupt, but no joy.

Suggestions welcome. Everything still seems to work fine if I just boot the .59 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Fixed. Turns out Sophos AV on-access scanning was causing this problem. Disabling SAV allowed the package to unpack and install properly. Lesson learned.